# Is there a way to break up a getline?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;


const int N = 20;

void instructions()
{cout << "* To quit or print a bill, enter 0 when asked to Enter an item number." << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "* To cancel orders, enter the item number of the item to cancel" << endl;
cout << "  and then enter the negative of the number of orders to cancel." << endl;
cout << "  (e.g., -3 to cancel 3 orders of the selected item)." << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "--- MENU --------------------" << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

ifstream infile; // init input file
string foods; // food name
float costs; // food cost
string food[N]; // food array
float cost[N]; // cost array
int cnt; // counter
char tab = '\t';


cout << setprecision(2) << fixed; // shows decimal two places
// below if file argument isn't found return error message
if(argc != 2)
{
    cerr << "File not found." << endl;
    return 1;
}

infile.open(argv[1]); // opens the user inputed file
    cnt = 0;// sets up counter for while loop
       infile >> foods >> costs;    // initalizes the while loop


instructions();

// While loop reads in information from input file and uses a count.
while(infile &&  cnt < N)
{

     food[cnt]= foods;
     cost[cnt] = costs;
     cout << cnt << ": " << food[cnt] << tab << cost[cnt] << endl;
     ++cnt;

     infile >> foods >> costs;
}

cout << "Enter item number (0 to print bill): ";
cout << endl << cnt;

return 0;
}
```

Object: The program reads in a menu file. The name of the food goes to an array and the cost goes to an array. The issue I'm having is that when words have a space in them it throws the whole thing off. I know I need to use a getline, but I'm not exactly sure how to break a getline into name // cost. Can someone help or show some type of example.

```
Hamburger    1.89
Cheeseburger 2.29
French Fries 1.59
Onion Rings  1.59
Soda         1.29
Iced Tea     1.29
```

Comment: What does the menu file look like? What separates the name of the items and the prices?

Comment: Hamburger 1.89
Cheeseburger 2.29
French Fries 1.59
Onion Rings 1.59
Soda  1.29
Iced Tea         1.29

Comment: thats not formatted hamburger 1.89 is its own line so each item and price has its own line

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::getline()` in a loop to read each line, then use `std::find_if()` to find first digit of that line. That's the position where to split the string. I'll leave it to you to trim the trailing whitespace from the food name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    istringstream is(
R"(Hamburger    1.89
Cheeseburger 2.29
French Fries 1.59
Onion Rings  1.59
Soda         1.29
Iced Tea     1.29
)");

    string s;
    while( getline( is, s ) )
    {
        auto it = find_if( begin( s ), end( s ), []( char c ){ return isdigit( c ); } );
        if( it != end( s ) )
        {
            string name( begin( s ), it );
            string price( it, end( s ) );
            cout << "\nFood: " << name << "\nPrice: " << price << endl;   
        }
    }    
}
```

[Live Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66329045f0ece733)

## More robust solution

As commenter noted, the above solution doesn't work if food name contains digits. To fix that we can use [`reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) to parse each line in reverse. The `reverse_iterator` will be obtained by calling free functions [`crbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) (const reverse begin) and [`crend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) (const reverse end).

If your version of STL doesn't provide these yet, you can replace them by the related `std::string` methods `line.crbegin()` and `line.crend()` (remove the `c` if even these are not available).

The first token found in reverse will be our price. From the "reverse end" of the price we parse further backwards to skip the whitespace between name and price.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    istringstream is(
R"(Hamburger    1.89
Cheeseburger 2.29
French Fries 1.59
Onion Rings  1.59
Soda 24      1.29
Iced Tea     free
)");

    string line;
    while( getline( is, line ) )
    {
        auto itLineRevEnd = crend( line );

        // Find end (reverse begin) of price token.
        auto itPriceRevBegin = find_if( crbegin( line ), itLineRevEnd, []( char c ){ return ! isspace( c ); } );
        if( itPriceRevBegin != itLineRevEnd )
        {
            // Find begin (reverse end) of price token.
            auto itPriceRevEnd = find_if( itPriceRevBegin, itLineRevEnd, []( char c ){ return isspace( c ); } );
            if( itPriceRevEnd != itLineRevEnd )
            {
                // Find end (reverse begin) of name.
                auto itNameRevBegin = find_if( itPriceRevEnd, itLineRevEnd, []( char c ){ return ! isspace( c ); } );
                if( itNameRevBegin != itLineRevEnd )
                {
                    // Call reverse_iterator::base() to turn them into forward iterators (otherwise strings would be reversed).
                    string name( itLineRevEnd.base(), itNameRevBegin.base() );
                    string price( itPriceRevEnd.base(), itPriceRevBegin.base() );

                    cout << "\nFood: \"" << name << "\"";
                    cout << "\nPrice: ";

                    try
                    {
                        double priceNum = stod( price );
                        cout << priceNum << endl;     
                    }
                    catch( std::exception& e )
                    {
                        // Conversion error or out-of-range.
                        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
                    }                    
                }    
            }            
        }
    }    
}
```

[Live Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c84582a6cac40cc)

Output:

```
Food: "Hamburger"   
Price: 1.89

Food: "Cheeseburger"
Price: 2.29

Food: "French Fries"
Price: 1.59    

Food: "Onion Rings"
Price: 1.59

Food: "Soda 24"
Price: 1.29

Food: "Iced Tea"
Price: ERROR
```

Comment: One issue with this solution is if the name itself contains any digits. A better approach might be to work backwards from the end of each line looking for the first non-space

Comment: @harmic thanks for suggestion, I have added a 2nd example.